# IO monad prevents short circuiting of embedded mapM?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, traversal, io-monad, strictness

Somewhat mystified by the following code. In non-toy version of the problem I'm trying to do a monadic computation in a monad Result, the values of which can only be constructed from within IO. Seems like the magic behind IO makes such computations strict, but I can't figure out how exactly that happens.

The code:

```
data Result a = Result a | Failure deriving (Show)

instance Functor Result where
  fmap f (Result a) = Result (f a)
  fmap f Failure = Failure

instance Applicative Result where
  pure = return
  (<*>) = ap

instance Monad Result where
  return = Result
  Result a >>= f = f a
  Failure >>= _ = Failure

compute :: Int -> Result Int
compute 3 = Failure
compute x = traceShow x $ Result x

compute2 :: Monad m => Int -> m (Result Int)
compute2 3 = return Failure
compute2 x = traceShow x $ return $ Result x

compute3 :: Monad m => Int -> m (Result Int)
compute3 = return . compute

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let results = mapM compute [1..5]
  print $ results
  results2 <- mapM compute2 [1..5]
  print $ sequence results2
  results3 <- mapM compute3 [1..5]
  print $ sequence results3
  let results2' = runIdentity $ mapM compute2 [1..5]
  print $ sequence results2'
```

The output:

```
1
2
Failure
1
2
4
5
Failure
1
2
Failure
1
2
Failure
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nice test cases. Here's what's happening:

- in `mapM compute` we see laziness at work, as usual. No surprise here.
- in `mapM compute2` we work inside the IO monad, whose `mapM` definition will demand the whole list: unlike `Result` which skips the tail of the list as soon as `Failure` is found, `IO` will always scan the whole list. Note the code:

  ```
  compute2 x = traceShow x $ return $ Result x
  ```

  So, the above wil print the debug message as soon as each element of the list of IO actions is accessed. All are, so we print everything.
- in `mapM compute3` we now use, roughly:

  ```
  compute3 x = return $ traceShow x $ Result x
  ```

  Now, since `return` in IO is lazy, it will *not* trigger the `traceShow` when returning the IO action. So, when `mapM compute3` is run, *no message* is seen. Instead, we see messages only when `sequence results3` is run, which forces the `Result` -- not all of them, but only as much as needed.
- the final `Identity` example is also quite tricky. Note this:

  ```
  > newtype Id1 a = Id1 a
  > data Id2 a = Id2 a
  > Id1 (trace "hey!" True) `seq` 42
  hey!
  42
  > Id2 (trace "hey!" True) `seq` 42
  42
  ```

  when using a `newtype`, at runtime there is no boxing/unboxing (AKA lifting) involved, so forcing a `Id1 x` value causes `x` to be forced. With `data` types this does not happen: the value is wrapped in a box (e.g. `Id2 undefined` is not equivalent to `undefined`).

  In your example, you add an `Identity` constructor, but that is from the `newtype Identity`!! So, when calling

  ```
  return $ traceShow x $ Result x
  ```

  the `return` here does not wrap anything, and the `traceShow` is immediately triggered as soon as `mapM` is run.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, chi. May I ask how you know that the IO definition of mapM is strict and that return is lazy?

Comment: @NioBium `Failure >>= f = Failure` discards the `f`: there's no need to proceed further on the monadic chain. IO has a lower lever definition which is not easily written, but -- barring exceptions -- `action >>= f` will always call `f` since one expects that e.g. `action >> print 4` will eventually print 4 no matter what `action` does (barring IO exceptions and non-termination).

Comment: Right. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Your `Result` type appears to be virtually identical to `Maybe`, with

```
Result <-> Just
Failure <-> Nothing
```

For the sake of my poor brain, I'll stick to `Maybe` terminology in the rest of this answer.

chi explained why `IO (Maybe a)` does not short-circuit the way you expected. But there *is* a type you can use for this sort of thing! It's essentially the same type, in fact, but with a different `Monad` instance. You can find it in `Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe`. It looks something like this:

```
newtype MaybeT m a = MaybeT
  { runMaybeT :: m (Maybe a) }
```

As you can see, this is just a `newtype` wrapper around `m (Maybe a)`. But its `Monad` instance is very different:

```
instance Monad m => Monad (MaybeT m) where
  return a = MaybeT $ return (Just a)
  m >>= f = MaybeT $ do
    mres <- runMaybeT m
    case mres of
      Nothing -> return Nothing
      Just a -> runMaybeT (f a)
```

That is, `m >>= f` runs the `m` computation in the underlying monad, getting `Maybe` something or other. If it gets `Nothing`, it just stops, returning `Nothing`. If it gets something, it passes that to `f` and runs the result. You can also turn any `m` action into a "successful" `MaybeT m` action using `lift` from `Control.Monad.Trans.Class`:

```
class MonadTrans t where
  lift :: Monad m => m a -> t m a

instance MonadTrans MaybeT where
  lift m = MaybeT $ Just <$> m
```

You can also use this class, defined somewhere like `Control.Monad.IO.Class`, which is often clearer and can be much more convenient:

```
class MonadIO m where
  liftIO :: IO a -> m a

instance MonadIO IO where
  liftIO m = m

instance MonadIO m => MonadIO (MaybeT m) where
  liftIO m = lift (liftIO m)
```